# Launch image storyboard added Imageview , but Changing image in asset folder does not actually reflect on Device?

Tags: ios, swift, image, splash-screen, launchimage

I have added a UIImageView in Launchscreen.storyboard with one image say (splash.png) , but Changing image in asset folder with same name (splash.png) Image , does not actually change on Device instead it shows blank white or same old image as if it have gotten stuck on it. Any idea why is this happening?

My requirement is to change the splash screen in build time and by only changing the  image (with same name) in asset folder.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: I remember tweaking my launch screen image and not seeing the change. IIRC, I needed to reset the device (if using the simulator) and delete the app (if using the device) in order to see the new image.

Comment: I have already done all these above things :(

Comment: try to run in a different simulator, if it loads as you predicted then it is the bug others are mentioning about the content data in simulators.

Comment: Please remove images with same name, and add it again, By drag and drop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found other solution for launch image.

1. Delete launch.storyboard
2. Add image assets (New iOS Launch Image)
3. Go to Project Setting -> General -> App Icons and Launch Images
4. Select LaunchImage at Launch Image source
5. Now while testing , just change the images in image set of LaunchImage.
6. this will show the change in splash screen without deleting or reseting the device.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a weird issue that everyone faces at some point of time.

For the simulator, resetting content and settings worked for me.

Got to `Simulator` > `Reset Content and Settings`

Sometimes you need to restart the simulator or even Xcode if that matters. If it's the device, try deleting the app or restarting it would fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help , but user will not reset content and setting for the device everytime .